# Adding to seeds.rb of an existing project, Validation errors and undefined methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I've been tasked with adding seeds to an existing Rails project. I've been given a list of twelve survey names and I'm supposed to create them all, storing their id (position in the list of surveys) and name values, then loop over them and add a placeholder survey_question to each. I know how to do it if I were to create a new migration, redefining survey_question as an attribute of survey, but I'm supposed to work with the existing structure where survey and survey_question are distinct classes. And I've hit a wall.

My thinking was to put all the survey names in an array, thus ordering them automatically when the database is seeded:

```
surveys = [
  "SurveyA",
  "SurveyB",
  "SurveyC",
  "SurveyD",
  "SurveyE",
  "SurveyF",
  "SurveyG",
  "SurveyH",
  "SurveyI",
  "SurveyJ",
  "SurveyK",
  "SurveyL"
]
```

Then write an each loop that instantiates the Survey class and stores the given name as the name attribute of the database entry. Within that same loop I define survey_question as a placeholder question (which some of you may recognize), and attempt to append it to the Survey being created with the << operator. This is my first point of failure:

```
surveys.each do |survey|
  survey_question = SurveyQuestion.create(body: "What is the average flight speed velocity of an unladen swallow?")
  Survey.create(name: survey) << survey_question
end
```

Great, I've written a loop. I need to verify that it does what I want it to do. So I go to re-seed the database and run rake db:seed. When I do, however, I get a validation error from a line in the seeds.rb file that came with the project. See here:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `<<' for #<Survey:0x007fb01fe1a3d0>
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activemodel-4.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:155:in `method_missing'
/Users/bwstud/Box Sync/Work/Codefellows/erp/db/seeds.rb:95:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/bwstud/Box Sync/Work/Codefellows/erp/db/seeds.rb:93:in `each'
/Users/bwstud/Box Sync/Work/Codefellows/erp/db/seeds.rb:93:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:540:in `load_seed'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:154:in `load_seed'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:181:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:140:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed
```

Here is the offending line (25) from the seeds:

```
  #create seed region
  usa = Region.create!(name: "USA")
```

So I thought, maybe for some wierd reason this was written when the database was created and cannot be overwritten, so if I clear out the database and start anew, it will populate without complaining. I ran rake db:reset. Wrong. At this point I realized there was an error in the way I'd written my each loop above. The error message told me that << is an undefined method for the survey object it was attached to. Here's that messsage.

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `<<' for #<Survey:0x007fb01fe1a3d0>
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activemodel-4.0.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:155:in `method_missing'
/Users/bwstud/Box Sync/Work/Codefellows/erp/db/seeds.rb:95:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/bwstud/Box Sync/Work/Codefellows/erp/db/seeds.rb:93:in `each'
/Users/bwstud/Box Sync/Work/Codefellows/erp/db/seeds.rb:93:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:540:in `load_seed'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:154:in `load_seed'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:181:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/bwstud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/activerecord-4.0.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:140:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed
```

As a final point of data I checked out what was actually in the database, just to see what was there. This is the result of `SELECT * FROM "regions";`:

```
erp_development=# SELECT * FROM "regions"
erp_development-# ;
 id | name |         created_at         |         updated_at         | default_email_sig 
----+------+----------------------------+----------------------------+-------------------
  1 | USA  | 2014-08-01 17:13:06.733146 | 2014-08-01 17:13:06.733146 | 
(1 row)
```

So now I'm good and stuck. I've been learning as much as I can but my understanding of Ruby and Ruby on Rails is entry-level at best. If anyone out there in Stack-land can help shed some light on this for me I will forever be in your debt.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 2):

<< is Ruby Array method. Survey.create(name: survey) won't return you array, so this is the reason why it fails. 
According to the documentation .create method returns the resulting object instead! http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class

```
survey = Survey.create(name: survey)
survey.survey_questions << question
```

The code above should work!

Comment: This is awesome, thank you, but I'm still fighting the validation error from the Region seed. Using your code I no longer see an undefined method error when I reset the database, but I'm still not populating the surveys table. Is there anything else I can tell or show you to make sense of this? Thanks!

Comment: You can try Region.find_or_create_by_name(name: "USA")! This will make sure that record is created only if it doesnt exist in database so validation wont fail!

Answer (score 0):

The `<<` method just modifies the returning value of `survey.survey_questions`, it does not modify the object itself. You should use modifying methods like `=` or `+=`. Anyway, I think this is a cleaner way to do the same:

```
surveys.map do |survey|
  Survey.create! do |s|
    s.name = survey
    s.survey_questions.build(body: "What is the average flight speed velocity of an unladen swallow?")
  end
end
```